# XPATH : Get Preceding Childrens

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the below XML structure where DIV2 and DIV3 are inside DIV1.
I wanted to count the number of *topic elements under DIV1 when my context is DIV2/DIV3.

So here I wanted to return "2" since DIV1 has 2 elements (Atopic and Btopic).
And  return "2" since DIV1 has 2 elements (Atopic and Btopic) when used from DIV3. Similarly child of DIV4 should return "1".

The only consideration is the body/division's children need to be counted and not the division/division

```
  <body>
      <division>
         ....DIV1....
        <Atopic> .. </Atopic>
        <Btopic> .. </Btopic>
           <division>
              .....DIV2..........
              <Atopic> .. </Atopic>
              <Btopic> .. </Btopic>
           </division>  
            <division>
              .....DIV3..........
              <Atopic> .. </Atopic>
              <Btopic> .. </Btopic>
           </division>
      </division>
      <division>
       ....DIV4....
       <Ctopic> .. </Ctopic>
      </division>
    <body>
```

pls help to achieve this via xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only consideration is the body/division's children need to be
>   counted and not the division/division

I *think* that would translate to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')])"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works well :)                                                                         Is it possible to exclude Btopic from the XPath logic so that it return 1 in both the DIV cases.

Comment: Just add another predicate `[not(self::Btopic)]`.

Comment: count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')] [not(self::introtopic)] ) is this correct