# XPATH : Count Preceding Div element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

When the context points to division/division/*topic , I wanted to count all topic tags under body/division and also add result to count of previous body/division/division tag.

Output = All topics under body/division + count of body/division/division

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <body>
       <division>
          <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
          <Btopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Btopic</longtitle></Btopic>
          <Ctopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Ctopic</longtitle></Ctopic>
          <division>
             <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1.1 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
          </division>
          <division>
                <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1.2 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
          </division>
       </division>
       <division>
            <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
            <Dtopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2 Dtopic</longtitle></Dtopic>
          <division>
             <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2.1 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
          </division>
           <division>
             <Ctopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2.2 Ctopic</longtitle></Ctopic>
          </division>
       </division>
    </body>
```

So for example

1. If my context is in Div 1/2 , the logic should count all *topics under body/division1. So it should return 3 (Atopic,Btopic,Ctopic). Here there is no preceding body/division/division element. So o/p = 3+0 = 3
                                                                                     2.Similarly from Div1/3 it should count the *topics under body/division tag i.e             3 and also count preceding body/div/div (i.e 3 + 1 = 4) .
2. When context is Div2/1 the counter should only consider the *topics under body/division2.
   So if I use the logic from Div2/1 Atopic , it should return "2" since Div2 tag (body/division) has 2 topics and no preceding body/div/div . Output = 2 . Here the preceding body/division/division should be considered for Div2 tag and Div1's body/division/division should NOT be accounted. In short the body/division/division should be reset when new body/division is encountered.

pls advice.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531286/xpath-get-preceding-childrens

Comment: P.S. Your example would be much clearer if (a) the divisions had a unique id attribute and (b) the topics had unique names and (c) it were properly indented. It's also not clear what exactly `.... DIV 1 ......` etc. are supposed to be; if they are elements, why not make them elementa?

Comment: hello Michael , the difference is I also need to add division/division to *topic i.e       "count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')])".                                                                                                   your sol was perfectly fine when considering the *topics under body/division. But I also need division/division to be added to the count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')]) result so that when context is 1/3 it returns (3 topics under body/div and 1 div/div = 4)

Comment: Div1/2 and 1/3 are child under Div1. Similarly Div2/1 is child of Div2. Just to show its division

Comment: I am afraid it's not any clearer now.

Comment: I have rephrased my issues , can you pls suggest

Comment: Ill put in a simpler way , pls help in framing logic so that body/div/div is counted. So for ex. from Div1/2 the count =0 . from 1/3 count=1. And from 2/1 count = 0 . Here for 2/1 it should only consider fresh body/div/div and not prev elements for Div1.

Comment: I made 4 suggestions how to make your question clearer; you did not take any of them. I also suggest you learn the meaning of `preceding` and `preceding-sibling` in XPath: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only guessing here, but it seems to me you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')])  + count(../preceding-sibling::division)"/>
```

Untested, because I don't know how to test this against your code.

Comment: Sorry Michael , count(preceding-sibling::division) return 0 everywhere.           The logic count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')]) works fine for requirement.                                                                          But all i wanted to have is to count previous div/div tag too. I tried using count(preceding::division[parent::division]) but it adds the count of div/div elements of DIV1 to the result of DIV2. pls help , i am bit lost in this

Comment: I have made changes to the XML , the sample XML does not have any attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael ! it worked . Thanks for your patience